# Mercurial/TortoiseHg responds with "abort: destination does not support push"

Tags: mercurial, push, tortoisehg, abort

I want to push a repository from my computer to a repository on a remote site for the purpose of synchronizing the files.  TortoiseHg seems to correctly identify outgoing changesets, but when I try to push the changes,  TortoiseHg responds with "abort: destination does not support push" with "Push to https://myid:ps@mydomain.com aborted, ret 255" in the status bar at the bottom.  The log file includes "(falling back to static-http)"

I've googled but I'm getting nowhere.  What does "abort: destination does not support push" mean in English?  What doesn't support push? What is the "destination"?  Is it the settings in the config files in the repo that make it so the destination doesn't support push?  Is it the way the server is set up?

One of the responses to 27967022 "Your destination does not support push, or push is disabled"  So how does one enable push?

Answer (score 1):

If you use hgweb on the server side, to allow pushing to a repository, add

```
[web]
  allow_push = *
```

to its `.hg/hgrc` on the server or in your `hgweb.config`. You can also allow pushing only for specific users by listing them instead of `*`. This is documented [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep#Allow_pushing_to_the_repository).

If that is not the case and you just use the https server to serve the repo as files, you'll not be able to push via https. In that case, your most likely option is to push via ssh, as in

```
hg push ssh://myid@mydomain.com/path/to/repo
```

This requires that you have ssh access to the server and that the repository lies in `$HOME/path/to/repo`. For an absolute path (if the repository lies in `/path/to/repo` and not below `$HOME`), push to `ssh://myid@mydomain.com//path/to/repo` (note the double slash).

If you always push to the same destination, you can add this path to your local `.hg/hgrc`:

```
[paths]
default-push = ssh://myid@mydomain.com/path/to/repo
```

so that you can then just use `hg push`.

Comment: I added [web]   allow_push = * to .hg/hgrc to the repo as instructed.  I get the same message.

Comment: I take from your comment to @Ry4an's answer that you don't have hgweb on the server side, which you'll need for `allow_push` (a plain https server doesn't know to parse these config files or what any of the stuff in them means). You'll not be able to push via https without server side support for it, so most likely you'll have to do it through ssh (I do hope you have ssh access to your server). I added instructions how to do that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are you running for your mercurial server on mydomain.com?  If it's hgweb, then @wintermute has your answer.  If you're serving static HTTP (using Apache, nginx, etc.) then your server is setup for clone or pull, but not push.  More likely you just need to enable push like @wintermute is saying.

Comment: I'm not running a mercurial server on mydomain.com.  I don't understand why I would need to do that.  Isn't mercurial just comparing one repo to another?  I should add that I don't control the server--the web hosting owns it.

Comment: You'ree saying you just want to compare two repos, but you're using the `push` command, which pushes new data into a repo.  If you want to compare them we can help you do that, but if you want to push, you need to be running a server there.

Comment: "if you want to push, you need to be running a server there."   That explains my problem.  I assumed that mercurial works over http.  It doesn't.  Thanks to both wintermute and Ry4an for their responses.

Comment: It does work over HTTP, but HTTP is a protocol.  The HTTP server your using provides a read-only view of files on disk, so when Mercurial is talking HTTP to your web server you can do read operations only. If you run mercurial as a server process instead of or proxied-to-by your static-file-views-only web server then you have a read/write existence. Or if you don't want a new server process it can do read/write over ssh, but that's not a requirement for a write existence -- HTTP can do it, but it's gotta be HTTP to a server that's built for read-write operations and the one you're using isn't.